# How to memoize the result of a property of a Discriminated Union in F#

Tags: f#, singleton, memoization, discriminated-union

I have a Discriminated Union ("DU") type and a property OR method which computes something based on the DU instance. I am trying to achieve a pattern where the instance property performs the calculation the first time it is requested and then remembers the result - akin to a Singleton Pattern in Object Oriented Terms.

I am finding this challenging without the aid of a local instance variable to store the state of things...

I have tried simple memoization of a method but I then run into the problem of not having anywhere (in the instance) to store the memoized result.

Note: there will be many instances of this DU type in my application.

## Code

```
// Terrible mutable variable needed alongside the DU to achieve a singleton-like pattern
let mutable result: int option = None

type DU = 
    | Good of int
    | Bad of int

with
    // behaves like a Singleton
    member this.GetSomething = 
        match result with
        | None ->        
            printfn "Big bad side-effect to let us know it's a first time"
            // big bad calculation that we only want to do once
            let x = 1 + 1
            // "memoize" it
            result <- Some x
            x
        | Some y -> y


let instance = Good 1
let f1 = instance.GetSomething  // first time
let f2 = instance.GetSomething  // second call - no side effect1
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some code here

Comment: You can have properties and methods defined for DU

Comment: @Petr code sample provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't memoize *inside* of an immutable value, because memoization involves *changing* and maintaining state.

Obviously, you can do it *outside* of an immutable value:

```
let smth = getSomething "foo"
```

As long as you reuse `smth` instead of calling `getSomething "foo"` again, you've essentially memoized the result. This is safe if `getSomething` is [referentially transparent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)); otherwise, it's not.

From the sample code posted in the OP, it looks more like you're looking for [lazy initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286), which you can get from the [`Lazy<T>` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331). You'll still need an *object* in which to store the `Lazy<T>` instance, though.

```
open System

type MyObject() =
    let result =
        lazy
        printfn "Big bad side-effect to let us know it's a first time"
        // big bad calculation that we only want to do once
        1 + 1
    member this.GetSomething = result.Value
```

As you can see, in F# you can also use `lazy` expressions for this.

```
> let mo = MyObject ();;    
val mo : MyObject

> let smth1 = mo.GetSomething;;
Big bad side-effect to let us know it's a first time    
val smth1 : int = 2

> let smth2 = mo.GetSomething;;    
val smth2 : int = 2
```

The `MyObject` class may look immutable, but that's only because state is being kept inside of the `lazy` expression.

Comment: Thanks. I presume that this can't be applied to a DU because the DU can't have a `let declaration`?

Comment: @Sam I think that's correct; at least, I can't think of any way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This way it is possible to have a lazy inside a DU.
Because the type is Lazy.

```
type DU = 
    | Good of Lazy<int>  // Lazy not lazy
    | Bad  of Lazy<int>  

type MyObject() =
    let result =
        lazy(
        printfn "Big bad side-effect to let us know it's a first time"
        // big bad calculation that we only want to do once
        1 + 1) |> Good
    member this.GetSomething = result

let mo = MyObject()
let f() =
    match mo.GetSomething with
    | Good x -> x.Value
    | Bad  y -> y.Value

f()
f()
```

Output

```
Big bad side-effect to let us know it's a first time
val it : int = 2

> 
val it : int = 2
```